# GetCookies() returns null in WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have two projects, one is client other is API provider. When I send request to api provider 'request.Headers.GetCookies()' have values on the client part but in

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var test1 = context.Request.Headers.ToList().FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key == "Cookie");
```

test1 is null and in

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
          var test2 = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies();
```

test2 is null, this is how I send request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostToApiProvider(RequestViewModel requestModel)
{
    var request = new HttpResponseMessage();
    // Here I add cookie header in request for authentification
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count != 0)
        {
            var cookieList = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
            {
                cookieList.Add(Request.Cookies[i].Value);
            }

            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieList);
        }
    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    var testRequestCookies = request.Headers.GetCookies();
return View("SomeView", model)
```

request and testRequestCookies (before and after call to api provider) will have cookie values , please see the screenshoot :

[CookieObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxVUf.png)

If I can help with more code, please ask. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to get a cookie value

```
private async Task<string> GetCookieValue(string url, string cookieName)
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    })
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == cookieName);
            return cookie?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```